# Overlay Dynamic FPS on Surface TextureView

Tags: android, count, frame-rate, android-camera2

I am new to android, I got a task to display FPS(dynamic) and elapsed time since Camera Open.
I got an android basic sample project where it will display the camera in surface Texture view.
but I did not find a way to get the frames count or FPS rate so that I can overlay this data on surface Texture view.
I just wanted to know whether we can get this data from Camera2 API? if yes please share the related links or code snipet or idea to get this.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the output of CaptureResults for each frame. They contain a variety of metadata about captured camera frames, including the [start of exposure time](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult#sensor_timestamp) for each frame.  You can use that to calculate frame rates.